# How to run Java program in terminal with external library JAR

Tags: java, jar

This should be simple but I have never done it before and didn't find any solution.

I am currently using Eclipse to code my program, which imports some external JAR library such as google data api library. I can use Eclipse to compile/build/run the program.

But now I want to run it in terminal, so where should I put those JAR files, and how to build and run the program?

Thanks!

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can do :

1) `javac -cp /path/to/jar/file Myprogram.java`

2) `java -cp .:/path/to/jar/file Myprogram`

So, lets suppose your `current working directory` in terminal is `src/Report/`

```
javac -cp src/external/myfile.jar Reporter.java

java -cp .:src/external/myfile.jar Reporter
```

Take a look here to setup [Classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html)

Comment: For example, I put all the JAR files in `src/external/` and the source file is in `src/Report/Reporter.java`, can you give the specific commands?

Comment: replacing ';' with ':' in                                           java -cp .;src/external/myfile.jar Reporter                                  worked for me..

Comment: @sattu: I believe you are on a linux system.

Comment: to run with external jar and external path (jar and my clas are in the same directory) `/usr/bin/java -cp /home/username/folderx/j.jar:/home/username/folderx MyClass`

Comment: @RanRag I am on a Windows system and I had to use ";" instead of ":"

Comment: Is there any way to include those JAR files with only a few commands, and then never have to put those `-cp /dir/of/jar/file` commands again?

Comment: How to do the same if I have `jar` files in `libs`, `java` files in `src` and `class` files in `build/classes/main` (the dir tree was created to run from gradle but I'd like to compile from terminal).

Comment: What if there are multiple JAR files to be imported?

Comment: I tried the same. Successfully compiled the project but I got a `Stub` error. I was trying to use `android.util.Base64` package. At last I switched to `java`'s util package.

Comment: @DevZer0 modified the original code so that it works with Linux/Mac instead of Windows.

Comment: @RanRag - what if you wanted to run a war file with java command and include an external jar in that command? How would you do that?

Answer (score 7):

For compiling the java file having dependency on a jar

> javac -cp path_of_the_jar/jarName.jar className.java

For executing the class file

> java -cp .;path_of_the_jar/jarName.jar className

Answer (score 0):

1. you can set your classpath in the in the environment variabl CLASSPATH.
   in linux, you can add like
   CLASSPATH=.:/full/path/to/the/Jars, for example ..........src/external
   and just run in side ......src/Report/

Javac Reporter.java

java Reporter

Similarily, you can set it in windows environment variables.
for example, in Win7

Right click Start-->Computer
then Properties-->Advanced System Setting --> Advanced -->Environment Variables
in the user variables, click classPath, and Edit and add the full path of jars at the end.
voila

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your jar application "myapp.jar" has the following code snippet written inside it.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject("{ \"abc\" : \"def\" }");
        System.out.println(jo.toString());
    }
}
```

It is using the external library json.jar from which we imported "org.json.JSONObject".
Running the following command will result in an error.

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

Exception message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject at com.reve.Main.main(Main.java:10)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
> ... 1 more

We must include the json.jar file while running the jar file. We have to specify the class path of the file before building our myapp.jar file.

Inside META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/json.jar lib/example2.jar
Main-Class: com.reve.Main
```

Specify the external libraries separated by spaces under the Class-Path keyword. Then after building the project and the artifact, we can run the jar file by simply writing the same command we discussed above.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you should put your source code .java files in `src/`.
2. Second, you make `build/` folder in your root project
3. Third, you make a `jars/` folder in your root project

So, now you will have `src/` and `build/` and `/jars` under your root project

To compile

```
javac -d ./build -cp ./jars/itextpdf-5.5.13.3.jar:jars/pdfbox-app-2.0.27.jar src/*.java
```

To run:

```
java -cp ./build:./jars/itextpdf-5.5.13.3.jar:jars/pdfbox-app-2.0.27.jar Main
```