# ClassNotFound Exception for Jumblr

Tags: java, tumblr

I am using the "Jar with dependencies" build which is found http://tumblr.github.io/jumblr/

The code:

```
import com.tumblr.jumblr.JumblrClient;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        // Authenticate via OAuth
        JumblrClient client = new JumblrClient(
          "xyz",
          "xyz"
        );
        client.setToken(
          "xyz",
          "xyz"
        );
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter if I use the actual keys from Tumblr or not, when I compile with

```
javac -cp jumblr-0.0.6-jar-with-dependencies.jar App.java
```

When I run it with

```
java App
```

It comes up with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tumblr/jumblr/JumblrClient
        at App.main(App.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tumblr.jumblr.JumblrClient
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

I've placed the jumblr-0.0.6-jar-with-dependencies.jar in the same folder as App.java.

Any ideas on the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>  -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
>  -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
>                    A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
>                    and ZIP archives to search for class files.
> ```

Use:

```
javac -cp . App.java
```

or

```
javac -classpath . App.java
```

Assuming you have the jar in your current directory.

To answer your Edit: To run the compiled code you should use (without .java extension) :

```
java -cp jumblr-0.0.6-jar-with-dependencies.jar App
```

Comment: I tried both. Either way it could not find the JumblrClient class which is in the jar file, of which is in the same folder as App.java. It doesn't compile.

Comment: You have got something wrong. It works perfectly for me. Followed the exact steps you wrote. Here is a [screeshot](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ifny9z&s=5)

Comment: Sorry, my fault for not being clear, the exception happens during run time. I've edited the question so it's clearer. It compiles fine.

Comment: Solved it using the answer from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949413/how-to-run-java-program-in-terminal-with-external-library-jar). I compiled with `javac -cp jumblr-0.0.6-jar-with-dependencies.jar App.java` and run with `java -cp .;jumblr-0.0.6-jar-with-dependencies.jar App`. And the runtime problem seems to be gone.