# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pdfbox/pdfparser/

Tags: java, pdfbox

Below is the code that I am using, I've provided one pdf file and one text file as an input to command line.

```
import org.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import org.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentInformation;
import org.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class PDFTextParser {

    PDFParser parser;
    String parsedText;
    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper;
    PDDocument pdDoc;
    COSDocument cosDoc;
    PDDocumentInformation pdDocInfo;

    // PDFTextParser Constructor 
    public PDFTextParser() {
    }

    // Extract text from PDF Document
    String pdftoText(String fileName) {

        System.out.println("Parsing text from PDF file " + fileName + "....");
        File f = new File(fileName);

        if (!f.isFile()) {
            System.out.println("File " + fileName + " does not exist.");
            return null;
        }

        try {
            parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(f));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open PDF Parser.");
            return null;
        }

        try {
            parser.parse();
            cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
            pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
            parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An exception occured in parsing the PDF Document.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                if (cosDoc != null) cosDoc.close();
                if (pdDoc != null) pdDoc.close();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println("Done.");
        return parsedText;
    }

    // Write the parsed text from PDF to a file
    void writeTexttoFile(String pdfText, String fileName) {

        System.out.println("\nWriting PDF text to output text file " + fileName + "....");
        try {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fileName);
            pw.print(pdfText);
            pw.close();  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An exception occured in writing the pdf text to file.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }

    //Extracts text from a PDF Document and writes it to a text file
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java PDFTextParser  ");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        PDFTextParser pdfTextParserObj = new PDFTextParser();
        String pdfToText = pdfTextParserObj.pdftoText(args[0]);

        if (pdfToText == null) {
            System.out.println("PDF to Text Conversion failed.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\nThe text parsed from the PDF Document....\n" + pdfToText);
            pdfTextParserObj.writeTexttoFile(pdfToText, args[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

After Running this code via command line with 2 inputs one pdf file name and another text file name I am getting noClassDefFound exception. Below is the stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pdfbox/pdfparser/
PDFParser
        at PDFTextParser.pdftoText(PDFTextParser.java:42)
        at PDFTextParser.main(PDFTextParser.java:93)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        ... 2 more
```

After adding class path I am getting below Exceptions

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/fontbox/afm/AFMParser
        at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.getAFM(PDFont.java:350)
        at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.getAverageFontWidthFromAFMFile(PDFont.java:313)
        at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont.getAverageFontWidth(PDSimpleFont.java:231)
        at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.showString(PDFStreamEngine.java:276)
        at org.pdfbox.util.operator.ShowTextGlyph.process(ShowTextGlyph.java:80)
        at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:452)
        at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:215)
        at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:174)
        at org.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:336)
        at org.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.processPages(PDFTextStripper.java:259)
        at org.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:216)
        at org.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.getText(PDFTextStripper.java:149)
        at PDFTextParser.pdftoText(PDFTextParser.java:53)
        at PDFTextParser.main(PDFTextParser.java:93)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.fontbox.afm.AFMParser
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        ... 14 more
```

Comment: Do you have the library JAR file on your CLASSPATH when running the application?

Comment: Are you sure you have [the fontbox JAR file](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.fontbox.afm.AFMParser) on your CLASSPATH? Please show us the command you use to launch the application.

Comment: just one question more which jar files I need to add into classpath main "PDFBox-0.7.3.jar" file or all the files which are there in external folder?

Comment: below is the command that I've used..

java -cp .;C:\Users\Desktop\lib\PDFBox-0.7.3.jar PDFTextParser "xyz.pdf" "text.txt"

Comment: To eradicate the errors you are getting you need to add at least the font-box and the pdf-box JAR files (see my edited answer). It is possible that the application will throw new exceptions after you solve these two and you will have to add some more JARs.

Comment: This time I've tried with both the jar files using below command

java -cp .;C:\Users\Desktop\lib\PDFBox-0.7.3.jar;C:\eDWAM Automation_2\Selenium\Workspace\PdfTest
\external\FontBox-0.1.0-dev.jar PDFTextParser "xyz.pdf" "text.txt"

still it is not able to find fontbox main class though the jar is located at same position

Comment: please check the above comment.

Comment: What do you mean by fontbox main class? Do you mean AFMParser.java or Main.java or another one? You can unzip the JAR file and make sure that there really is a class with the given name inside the given package. Also make sure that you did not mistype the path.

Comment: after adding classpath its not giving any error related to fontclass now it is giving error for my class which is PDFTextParser ... now it is not able to find its main 

Could not find the main class: PDFTextParser. Program will exit

Comment: Do you run the command directly from the directory where the PDFTextParser class file is located? Otherwise you'd need to add path to the directory where the class file resides as well (instead of the current one).

Comment: yes I ran the class from the bin folder of Eclipse.

Answer (score 6):

When running a program with external dependencies (PDF parser in your case) in Java you have to include the appropriate JAR files to your CLASSPATH.

See [this other thread on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8949442/1103412) or [the documentation at Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html).

I have searched for the classes that cannot be found at jarfinder.com and it turns out you need to include (at least) two different JAR files - the [font box](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.fontbox.afm.AFMParser) and the [pdf box](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser) JARs.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/fontbox/afm/AFMPa
rser
        at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.getAFM(PDFont.java:350)
        at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.getAverageFontWidthFromAFMFile(PDFont.
java:313)
        at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont.getAverageFontWidth(PDSimpleFont
.java:231)
        at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.showString(PDFStreamEngine.java:276)
        at org.pdfbox.util.operator.ShowTextGlyph.process(ShowTextGlyph.java:80)

        at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:
452)

Comment: You cannot paste large chunks of text in a comment but you can edit your question and append more information. Also, could you post the command you use to launch the application?

Comment: k let me repost the complete logTrace

Comment: I've added the new log trace... is it something related to pdf fonts?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the fontbox jar from here
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/fontbox/1.8.5

If you're using maven
    
      org.apache.pdfbox
      fontbox
      1.8.5

Answer (score 2):

You need to include **fontbox-1.3.1** jar in the class path apart from **Apache pdfbox jar** which will fix your issue as PDFBox internally uses **fontbox-1.3.1**

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue inserting `transitive = true` inside my ivy file for pdfbox dependency.

```
<dependency org="org.apache.pdfbox" name="pdfbox" rev="1.8.11" transitive="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following dependencies to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-RC1</version>
</dependency>
```

then run `mvn clean` and `mvn install` the issue will be resolved.

Note: you can find the latest version of pdfbox and fontbox from the follwing link

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/fontbox/