# Unknown error with PDDocument declaration : PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am getting an error when i use the PDDocument and PDFTextStripper methods despite importing all the required libraries.

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.*;
import java.io.*;

public class importingPDF {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PDDocument pd;
         BufferedWriter wr;
         try {
                 File input = new File("C:\\Invoice.pdf");  // The PDF file from where you would like to extract
                 File output = new File("C:\\SampleText.txt"); // The text file where you are going to store the extracted data
                 pd = PDDocument.load(input);
                 System.out.println(pd.getNumberOfPages());
                 System.out.println(pd.isEncrypted());
                 pd.save("CopyOfInvoice.pdf"); // Creates a copy called "CopyOfInvoice.pdf"
                 PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                 wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output)));
                 stripper.writeText(pd, wr);
                 if (pd != null) {
                     pd.close();
                 }
                // I use close() to flush the stream.
                wr.close();
         } catch (Exception e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
                } 
             }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is issue related to jars not on the classpath.

Same kind of questions you can search here and solve your issue, Refer this [Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pdfbox/pdfparser/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503159/getting-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-pdfbox-pdfparser)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that Hardik. As you said, I apparently hadnt loaded the right jar files. The following were the jar files necessary!

```
import org.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import org.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException;
import org.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentInformation;
import org.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;
```