# PDFBox unsupported operation for convertToImage()

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to get pdf first page as jpg image. The program shows me some errors:

```
Apr 18, 2016 1:18:40 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: BDC
Apr 18, 2016 1:18:40 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: EMC
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/fontbox/afm/AFMParser
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.addAdobeFontMetric(PDFont.java:165)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.addAdobeFontMetric(PDFont.java:152)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.getAdobeFontMetrics(PDFont.java:122)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.<clinit>(PDFont.java:114)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:108)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFonts(PDResources.java:213)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.getFonts(PDFStreamEngine.java:607)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.SetTextFont.process(SetTextFont.java:59)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:557)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:268)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:235)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:215)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.convertToImage(PDPage.java:801)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.convertToImage(PDPage.java:732)
    at Main.main(Main.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.fontbox.afm.AFMParser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 16 more
```

Main.java:26 : `BufferedImage image = firstPage.convertToImage();`

Is there any possibility to get first page as image by using PDFBox?

Full code:

```
try {
            String sourceDir = "/home/linux/Downloads/test.pdf";
            String destinationDir = "/home/linux/Downloads/testImage";
            File sourceFile = new File(sourceDir);
            File destinationFile = new File(destinationDir);

                PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(sourceDir);
                PDPage firstPage = (PDPage) document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(1);

                String fileName = sourceFile.getName().replace(".pdf", "");

                    BufferedImage image = firstPage.convertToImage();
                    ImageIO.write(image , "jpg", new File(destinationDir +fileName+"_"+".jpg"));

                document.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I just need to parse first page as image.

Comment: mostly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503159/getting-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-pdfbox-pdfparser , fontbox is missing, see also https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/dependencies.html

Comment: It is because of font type as I understood. But how can I remove warnings? [link](http://s4.postimg.org/eag2cufct/Warnings.jpg)

Comment: That is a different question. The warning is typical for 1.8. Solution: update to 2.0. Don't forget to read the migration guide.

Comment: One can get even 1.8 to not show such warnings. Thus, @Munchmallow, are you bound to use a pre-2.0.0 version or not?

Comment: I am using 1.8.5. and PDFBox 1.8.10. I tried ten different pdfs, I get first page as image, and also get some warnings or info messages which are like the ones I showed them in my first comment. Should I update both fontbox and pdfbox to 2.0?

Comment: @Munchmallow if you're just starting with PDFBox, i.e. not bound to 1.8, then use 2.0 and delete all older versions. You'll get better quality images. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326562/apache-pdfbox-convert-pdf-to-images how to convert.

Comment: I have followed the link that is in your last comment. There are some font problems when converting(or parsing) to the image. e.g french words [original 1st page](http://s3.postimg.org/jpolrl8c3/original_Picture.jpg) and [parsed 1st page as jpg](http://s1.postimg.org/3xdyo011b/bad_Parsing.jpg). Also I am getting warnings for those characters which cannot be parsed.

Comment: @Munchmallow did you get this image with 2.0 or with 1.8? It's only 36 minutes between the two comments so I wonder whether you used 2.0.

Comment: No, I used 1.8 I will be using the images on my searching engine. I am trying to make a search table like amazon's and I am using 1.8 there. I believe It will take some time to update the codes to 2.0. I now prefer using 1.8.

Comment: @Munchmallow then you'll have to live with the rendering problems. Btw getting rid of the warnings, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311408/turning-off-hibernate-logging-console-output  and use the appropriate class.

Comment: @Munchmallow The 1.8 rendering code has numerous deficiencies fixed in 2.0.0 but works fine for a fair portion of the PDFs out there. Furthermore, you can simply ignore most of the INFOs *unsupported/disabled operation* (they are not WARNINGs, merely INFOs!) because they refer to instructions without influence on the optical appearance of the rendered page image.

Comment: I upgraded it to 2.0. I do not want to live with rendering problems. The Stackoverflow rules say that I need to open a new topic instead of asking it here. So I have just opened a topic.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698492/pdf-rendering-with-pdfbox-2-0-and-decrypting).
I believe font problem will be solved when I start using 2.0

Comment: *I believe font problem will be solved when I start using 2.0* - As you did not share a sample PDF, that is hard to tell. But there definitively are numerous improvements.

Answer (score 0):

[Convert a PDF file to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189314/convert-a-pdf-file-to-image)

Trying looking into this question, the "marked as correct answer" tells the correct way of how to approach your desire. :)

Comment: The referenced answer neither explains about the missing resource nor does it prevent the warnings as desired by the OP here.

Comment: I have followed that one and I do see these warnings [link](http://s4.postimg.org/eag2cufct/Warnings.jpg)