# i have created jar file but its showing the class defnotfound error? how to get away with this?

Tags: java, logging, portal

I am trying to implement the multiple log implementation from the single logger class and I have used jar file for dynamically loading the logger file based on module selection. i am getting an error shown below
 An error has occurred.
[The error message returned was: "Error in method main. com/grpf/Jarclass".

Please refer to the logs folder in your deployed application for additional error information.

Click here to hide the detailed error message.

Exception Error in method main. com/grpf/Jarclass

Stack Trace
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/grpf/Jarclass

```
static WebAppAccess rt;

public static void main(String args[]){
    CommonClassForLogFileSelection1();
}

public static String CommonClassForLogFileSelection1(){

    try{
        if(rt.getModelName().equals("qwe"))
        return "logf2";
        else
            return "CommonECPLogs";
    }catch(final Exception e){
        throw new WebAppRuntimeException( e, "PropertyFileSelectionHandler Has encountered an error while processing a profile" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you linking to external libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Include the jar in your CLASSPATH to be able to link/use it

This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949413/how-to-run-java-program-in-terminal-with-external-library-jar/8949442#8949442) should help you with that