# Class not found after jar export

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

It should be simple but I can't run my JAR file.

My error: 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/PDFont`

I'm trying to follow some post like this: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949413/how-to-run-java-program-in-terminal-with-external-library-jar/8949442#8949442)

But nothing.

I think this error is because I haven't take external libraries on my project.

How to create a JAR file with libraries in Intellij ?

Anyone have a solution ?

Comment: If you have a large application than you should use build tools like Maven or Ant !!

Comment: It's just a little application with a form. My form is used to create a PDF. That's why, i want to create a JAR file. But when i make it, i have this error (see my post ;) )

Comment: According to error, application not able to find that class at run time.. Extract jar file using 7 zip and check if PDFBox jar is available in build path or not !!

Comment: This is an IntelliJ question, so please set the appropriate label. I would have done it for you but there are several versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your classpath includes the jar

Comment: Question is: "How to create a JAR file with libraries in Intellij "

Answer (score 1):

1. go to File from File menu
2. click on Project Structure
3. choose Modules at the left panel
4. select Dependencies tab
   and start adding external jars.

After adding the dependencies, you can export your project as jar if you wish.

- Again go to File
- Project Structure

  - Project Settings
  - Artifacts
- extract Jar

  If you still get the error, please cross check your classpath for the missing class, you might have got classnotfound exception or ExceptionInInitializerError   before.

Answer (score 0):

Click on 
`File -> Project Structure->Artifacts->'+'->Jar->From modules with dependencies`-> Select the module folder and Main Class.Click on Apply and then you export the artifact

Now with all the required libraries in the class path your program should work as expected